# How to use implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3:15.0.0' not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the latest version of Android Studio 3.2 & Plugin. When I try to connect firebase it show me to add dependencies -implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3:15.0.0' for Firebase authentication | implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0' for Realtime Database | implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0' for Cloud Storage

When using these dependencies it connect Firebase properly but Sync Failed. How to Use these dependencies?

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue before. If there is the update available then update your android it will fix it. from my experience when I use the assistant to add the dependencies then it comes like this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

but the it is not correct update it with this
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'`
   or

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

or this

maybe this will help you 
[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is official documentation for help

Answer (score -1):

Update you firebase dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

Basically, remove the last ":15.0.0" part. You probably copied these from the firebase website and made a mistake while pasting

Comment: it sync successfully but Firebase Connect Tool Show (option 2. Add Firebase Authentication to your App) not connected with firebase. when this button click for add app with firebase it show to Add dependency - implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

Comment: Try changing 16.0.3 to 16.0.1 for core and auth